# Laravel | nginx config not finding assets

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I am currently trying to setup Laravel 6 with Docker and Nginx.

I have it all running through php-fpm and nginx and the actual app loads perfectly fine.

The issue that I am facing is that it cannot find any of the asset files.

I have the line at the top of my `layout.blade.php`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" />
```

I can see that the file does exist in the folder but it's always getting a 404 inside of Chrome.

I am using the default nginx config that is on the Laravel website with a few minor adjustments.

```
events {}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/html/public;

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        charset utf-8;

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        error_page 404 /index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass php:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
            deny all;
        }
    }
}
```

Navigating directly to the url `http://localhost/css/app.css` also gives me the Laravel default 404 page.

Any help would be appreciated its racking my brain!

I can also go into the container and see that all of the files are in the correct directories.

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `location` block that Laravel suggests, with the `$uri/` in it and see if that makes a difference:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try runing `npm run dev` inside the terminal in your project root folder, it is possible you didnt compiled your css/js files you get from the start. So you will not be able to get them properly, instead you'll get 404 response.